# Speech Recognition Services wav file from http Stream

Tags: .net, azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

When I try to download a wav file from an url to an AudioInputStream I get very poor transcription results.

```
HttpResponseMessage wavresponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{recordingUrl}.wav").ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
using var httpStream = await wavresponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(_speechOptions.Key, _speechOptions.Region);
speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "de-DE";

var reader = new BinaryReader(httpStream);
using var audioInputStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream();

//using var audioConfig2 = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput($"{recordingUrl}.wav");
using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioInputStream);
using var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

byte[] readBytes;
do
{
    readBytes = reader.ReadBytes(1024);
    audioInputStream.Write(readBytes, readBytes.Length);
} while (readBytes.Length > 0);

var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

var textRecognition = "";

recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
    {
        textRecognition += e.Result.Text;
    }
};

recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
{
    stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
};
recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
{
    stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
};

// Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

// Waits for completion.
// Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
// Stops recognition.
await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The same file gives very accurate results when I download the wav file and use the file as input rather than the http stream. I think something is probably wrong in this line, but I am not sure.

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(httpStream);
```

Comment: Here’s an example:

using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await httpStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
var reader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);

Comment: Thank you, but I still receive results that are not even close to what has been said. When reading the same audio data from the downloaded FIle the results are very accurate.

Comment: did you find the solution for this case? as I have the same issue

Comment: The only workaround I considered is to download the file which I think I remember doesn’t work on Linux.. I felt like this is probably a bug cause I do get results but they’re just very inaccurate.. I was hoping this would be fixed with future releases or the docs would be updated at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        HttpResponseMessage wavresponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        using var httpStream = await wavresponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await httpStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 44;
        var reader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
                    
        var audioFormat = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(8000, 16, 1);
        using var audioInputStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream(audioFormat);
        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioInputStream);
```

When reading from an url, the information from the WAV file currently can't be read dynamically with the SDK, so I had to hard code the audioFormat and start the memoryStream.Position at 44 bytes, because the audioformat information is stored in there.